# afther installing ubuntu and goes back to installtion menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

i have Toshiba c50 laptop and the hard drive has no OS as i formatted it . when installing Ubuntu 14.4 LTS using a usb the installation completes and asks for restart but it takes me back to the install menu. i have tried removing the usb but when i switch it on it says "Reboot and Select proper boot device or Insert boot media in selected boot device", i have checked the BIOS and made sure the HDD is the first priority. am i installing it wrong?
 please help i am new to all this
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the USB on another computer? You might have selected the wrong storage for installation. So you installed Ubuntu on the USB instead of your HDD, which could explain why there is no OS detected.